# Inequality including the minimum value of the Gamma function and the Champernowne constant .

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, gamma-function, products, constants

It's a problem I found unconventional :

Problem :

Let $0<x$ be a real the define :

### $$f\left(x\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{292}\left(\frac{n+1}{x!+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Shows that :

$$f(x)<1+C$$

Where $C$ is the Champernowne constant equal to $0.12345678910111213141516171819\cdots$

Taking derivative or logarithmic derivative the problem is to show that the value of the minimum of the Gamma's function is less than the well-know constant plus one .

We don't need a great accuracy and the approximation $x_{min}=0.4616\simeq\frac{\left(\pi-e+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}=I$ seems to works as well .

We have can also use the [Euler Reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)

Can we pretend to show it by hand ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: We have also $$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}\cdot K}^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot K}\prod_{n=1}^{292}\left(\frac{n+1}{x!+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}dx>C$$ Where $$K=0.123581321\cdots$$ (fibonnaci sequence)

Comment: The product over $n$ from $1$ to $\infty$ is $1.123894216727743$, so the cutoff must be important.